# What causes "Unknown command: 'mkmigrations'" in Django?

Tags: django, git

When attempting to view my Django app while being served locally I am encountering this error:

A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

It remains that way even when debug is false. The console shows:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.
are" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
```

and searching around I came across the suggestion to comment out

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
#    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

This does indeed fix the problem, in that the app does display, however when I go to the admin panel I get the message:

```
Site administration
You don't have permission to edit anything.
```

I figured I would just try and roll back to the last commit before I pushed the app to heroku and ran:

```
git reset --hard 'appropriate commit'
```

This did not seem to do anything at all. I still have the same situation as previously. Furthermore running:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

or

```
python manage.py migrate
```

results in

```
Unknown command: 'makemigrations'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

and

```
Unknown command: 'migrate'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Previously both of these commands worked just fine.

If it helps, I was trying to install [addthis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-addthis/1.0.1) to the app when things started breaking. Also after the git reset when I type git status I get:

```
Untracked files:
    blog/migrations/0005_join_ip_address.py
    blog/migrations/0006_auto_20150318_1716.py
    blog/migrations/0007_remove_join_ip_address.py
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Other details:

```
Django 1.6.5
Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0
Using a Virtualenv
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: `makemigrations` was introdiced in django 1.7 wasn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noticed, your Django version should be 1.7; this is caused by your installation of `django-addthis`.

The current version of `django-addthis` explicitly states `Django<=1.6.5` as a dependency. For some reason, this prompts `pip` to downgrade your installation:

```
$ pip install django-addthis
Downloading/unpacking django-addthis
  Downloading django-addthis-2.0.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:...) egg_info for package django-addthis

Downloading/unpacking Django>=1.4,<=1.6.5 (from django-addthis)
  Downloading Django-1.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.7MB): 6.7MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: django-addthis, Django
  Running setup.py install for django-addthis

  Found existing installation: Django 1.7.5
    Uninstalling Django:
      Successfully uninstalled Django
Successfully installed django-addthis Django
```

The last four lines show what happened when I tried this on one of my own Django 1.7 projects. `pip` happily downgrades your Django app. And since `virtualenv` dependencies are usually *not* stored in Git, you won't see this when you do a `git status`.

The only solution is to uninstall `django-addthis` and reinstall the correct Django version:

```
$ pip uninstall django-addthis && pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running a Django 1.7 project against an installed version of 1.6. Upgrade your Django installation.